# What's an elegant way to retrieve all times of the day (1 hour resolution) in DB2 without a backing table?

Tags: sql, time, db2, mainframe

I'm querying some data from a table in DB2/z which holds hourly data but occasionally skips some hours (if the clients don't send up details for that hour).

Since I'm feeding the data straight into a charting tool which needs a query to get the axis data, it sometimes has missing values from the time axis and looks ugly:

```
23.00 |===
22.00 |=====
14.00 |============
01.00 |==
00.00 |=
      +--------------------
```

We've been verboten from adding any helper tables like a 24-row table holding all the hours so I need a query in DB2 that will return *all* the hours of the day without a reliable backing table. I've been using the monstrous:

```
select '00.00' from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all select '01.00' from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all select '02.00' from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all select '03.00' from sysibm.sysdummy1
: : :
union all select '23.00' from sysibm.sysdummy1
order by 1
```

which is about as kludgy a solution I've ever seen, so I'd rather have something a little cleaner.

I've posted my own solution below but I'm open to anything simpler or more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following level-limited recursive call will give the desired range without a backing table. Without the limit on level, DB2 complains that the function may be infinitely recursive.

```
with trange(lvl, tm) as (
    select 1, time('00:00') from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all select lvl+1, tm + 1 hour from trange where lvl < 24
) select left(char(tm,iso),5) as hour from trange;
```

This gives:

```
HOUR 
-----
00.00
01.00
02.00
03.00
: : :
22.00
23.00
```

as desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
VALUES '00.00', '01.00', /* ... */, '23.00'
```

should work too, at least for me (on LUW 9.1+). :-) Still kludgey, but more compact.

In general, I've found that if you don't need the full power of `SELECT`, and don't need to name your columns, `VALUES` is a much simpler alternative.

If you do want to name your column, just throw the `VALUES` within a `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES /* ... */) AS foo (hour)
```

(With some versions of DB2, the `foo` is optional.)

---

Oh wow, I've just read the DB2 z/OS documentation for `VALUES`, and it's much wimpier compared to the LUW version. For z/OS, `VALUES` can only be used in the triggered action of a trigger. Sorry, paxdiablo. :-(

Comment: Is that in a select statement?

Comment: No, that _is_ a `SELECT` statement, just without the `SELECT` keyword. It works on the version of DB2 we have (LUW 9.1), but your mileage may vary with other editions/versions.

Comment: You've lost me Chris. That's not valid DB2 syntax with or without a select on the front AFAIK. I know values can be used as a part of an insert statement but that's no good for me here since I can't create a backing table.

Comment: Ah, hang on, I'll check our DB2 v9 setup, I've been using v8 ... Nope, not in v9 either. Is that the complete statement or a segment (it *may* be an LUW thing not yet on the mainframe)?

Comment: That's the complete statement. See my post edit to see how it gets used as a (fullselect). It may be a LUW-only feature, which would be a shame in your case.