# SSRS - Column Chart Thickness too thick

Tags: reporting-services

SSRS2008R2

**Problem:** Merchant1 works below.  MerchantX doesn't - see the widths of the columns span more than 1 day!

Raw data is displayed below each chart.
[image]

Here is chart data:

[image]

I'm using Scalar to give me 0 date values.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe check this link.. and play with the PointWidth (relative size) or PixelPointWidth of the column width....  [SSRS and Microsoft Charting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/seanboon/archive/2008/10/31/ssrs-and-microsoft-chart-control-chart-how-to-change-the-width-of-bars-and-columns.aspx)

PointWidths greater than 1.0 will give you an overlap... set to 0 and put the PixelPointWidth to something like 8 and see how that looks..

Comment: This does work.  Cheers. I've found that brining in 0 data in the SQL and using the Category Axis type to be more solid and doesn't produce this strangeness.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720381/sql-how-to-get-0-values